# Is it safe to add ubuntu to ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk

I have a 500GB hdd and when I installed ubuntu originally, I partitioned it to 200GB. But now I want to use all 500GB for ubuntu. I researched g-parted and it said that I could lose data if I partition the drive at this point. So, I used etcher and created a usb with ubuntu. When I start the computer with the usb in a port, the usb is what initializes. It asks me if I want to download ubuntu, which I do.

But, my question is, if I do this, will I lose the "original 200GB" that is almost completely filled with data? I don't have anywhere to make a backup for it. Or will it keep both ubuntus and all the data on the original ubuntu OS and allow me to choose which ubuntu I want to work with?

Comment: A live system on a USB dows nothing to your hard drive... except if you make an installation. But this is not what you want I gather. What's your purpose using your USB?

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what your acutal goal is? Why would you want to install two ubuntus on the same hard drive. Or do you just need more space for the existing system? If it's the latter, you could try to extend the existing partition, I assume that's what you tried with gparted? I'm not familiar with that tool, I tend to use fdisk. But either way, a warning is always reasonable when comes to partitioning since you *could* lose data if you make a mistake. Could you paste the output of `fdisk -l <YOUR_DRIVE>`?

Comment: at eblock & gc: I want to add more data to the hard drive. I'm going to use it as an external hdd backup. It doesn't matter to me if I put it on the first 200GB's or the last 300GB's so long as I can easily access it. I did not create the live usb to use it as a live usb, rather, to add a 2nd OS. I didn't try anything with g-parted out of fear of losing data. What constitutes "YOUR_DRIVE"? Is that my "user@servername" or, for ie, "sda1"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a backup is of course highly advisable. But if there is nothing (of importance) in partitions **beyond** your original 200GB (which I assume is the first partition on your disk - /dev/sda1?) then GParted, running from booted USB or a DVD (e.g. [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/)), should be able to remove the partitions above this and then expand this root partition so that your existing Ubuntu installation now has 500GB instead of 200GB.

I've assumed you have a vanilla and reasonably recent Ubuntu installation. If it is more bespoke (LVM, encryption, separate boot partition) then it might be harder.

There is no need to do a new second Ubuntu installation - why would you want that?

As I said at the start, having a backup is still a good idea.

Comment: at gogoud: I'm using the hdd as an external hdd for later use. Yes, recent ubuntu install. If I wanted to add windows OS to this hdd, would the ubuntu 200GB data be in harms way? It seems like people are always adding a 2nd OS without a problem. The live usb is just for adding a 2nd OS. If I have 2 ubuntu OS's that I can easily access, then I would think I wouldn't have a problem in the future so long as I can open the files on a different computer in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could loose your data, so make a back up. If you have a fully charged battery, and have external power attached. Then it will probably be OK, but make a backup of all important stuff (Backing up OS, is of little value, as you can re-install).

## An alternative

Create a new partition, using the rest of the drive, move your data to this new partition, and mount the new partition on `/home`.